# Workaround for pcmanfm "module directory not accessible"

Tags: pcmanfm

Environment: Ubuntu 14.04 + openbox. All udates/upgrades applied.

When I run pcmanfm, I get an error "modules directory is not accessible." Browsing the net, it appears a bug was filed and a fix is already in the source code. However, I don' want to download and build the source code on my machine. I would prefer waiting for the upgrade to be available in the standard ubuntu repository. Meanwhile, I am wondering if there is any workaround that I can use. Perhaps I could manually create the directory it is looking for.

Regards,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

I got this in termial when running pcmanfm in openbox session also
** (pcmanfm:1530): WARNING **: modules directory is not accessible

after creating the directory "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pcmanfm" the message disappeared